# How to retrieve array entries from a list of array in Cython

Tags: python, cython

I am trying to speedup the computation of a Python code using Cython. It does serve it's purpose. But I have a problem. The function basically returns a list of 2D arrays. Pseudo code looks like this:

```
def MyFunc(array2D):
   cdef list MytList=[array2D.copy()]
   for <some condition>:
      process/update array2D
      MyList.append(array2D.copy())
   return MyList
```

```
import numpy as np
List=MyFunc(np.random.random((5,5)))
```

When I use the function from Python, `List[nn]` for any value of `nn` does give me a 2D array. But in case of Cython it shows " < MemoryView of 'array' at 0x23cce5a8048 >". How do I retrieve the real array from this MemoryView thing?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, it's simple! I used:

```
np.asarray(List)
```